# JS exclude break timings from working hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to split the working time into working slots while excluding Break time.
We may have multiple working slots and multiple breaks but time could not overlap.

while excluding the break hours and splitting the working time.
To exclude the time slots Exclusion: True means exclude that time from the Exclusion: false object.

example: This is the array of objects with working hours and exclusion hours.

```
[
    {
       
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T01:00:44.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T13:00:08.000Z", 
        "exclusion": false
    },
    {
        
       
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T08:00:19.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T09:00:24.000Z",
        "exclusion": true
      
    },
    {
        
        
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T11:00:11.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T11:30:26.000Z",
        "exclusion": true
      
    }
]
```

And The output I want array of objects with updated working hours to display only working time slots.

```
[
    {
      
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T01:00:44.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T08:00:19.000Z",
    },
    {
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T09:00:24.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T11:00:26.000Z",
        
    },
    {
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T11:30:26.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T13:00:08.000Z",
        
    }
]
```

Then I am converting the time to display on the table like in the below example. This is for just understanding.
These are the working hours.

```
06:00-13:00
14:00-16:00 
16:30-18:00
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need.

Comment: Just need working hours. Exclude the break timings.
" exclusion: true  exclude that time",
9  to 18 are working hours.  12 to 13 and 16 to 16:30 is break timings.
the output I want :
9 - 12,
13 - 16,
16:30 - 18

Comment: What's that "output want" about?

Comment: I just updated my question. please look into this and let me know if any confusion.

Comment: Ok it makes more sense now. So, you need the time slot array. What about the last part? Is that another array you need?

Comment: This is for just understanding.
once I get the updated time array I will convert it accordingly.

Comment: After staring at your data. Can I assume your first array has times that has to be converted to +5 time? :p

Comment: yes, you  can convert the time to +5,

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided explanation with comments. Bear in mind that the results could very depending on your timezone. You could specify a time zone to get the same results everywhere but I didn't know that was needed.

```js
var input = [
    {
       
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T01:00:44.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T13:00:08.000Z", 
        "exclusion": false
    },
    {
        
       
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T08:00:19.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T09:00:24.000Z",
        "exclusion": true
      
    },
    {
        
        
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T11:00:11.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T11:30:26.000Z",
        "exclusion": true
      
    }
];


// Create a new function to add hours easily
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

// Function to split up an array into chunks
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size)
    result.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  return result;
}

// This could be diffferent in your region
const differenceTimezone = 5

// Let's split up the working times and breaks
var workingHours = input.filter(time => !time.exclusion)
var breaks = input.filter(time => time.exclusion)
var times = []

// We want to start & end of the day
var start = new Date(workingHours[0].startHours).addHours(differenceTimezone)
var end = new Date(workingHours[0].finishHours).addHours(differenceTimezone)

times.push(start)

// Get all the breaks
breaks.forEach(b => {
  var start = new Date(b.startHours).addHours(differenceTimezone)
  var end = new Date(b.finishHours).addHours(differenceTimezone)
  times.push(start,end)
})

times.push(end)

// The end result
var result = chunkArrayInGroups(times, 2).map((r) => { return {startHours: r[0], finishHours: r[1]}})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That's great.
is it possible to return the original array of objects with updated time?
I need this result.
`[
    {
      
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T01:00:44.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T08:00:19.000Z",
    },
    {
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T09:00:24.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T11:00:26.000Z",
        
    },
    {
        "startHours": "2023-07-13T11:30:26.000Z",
        "finishHours": "2023-07-13T13:00:08.000Z",
        
    }
]
`

Comment: I made an edit. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me a lot. I am also handling the scenarios if we have multiple time exclusion true and multiple exclusion false. 
for example, we have multiple work shifts and breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Converting strings to Date and vice versa, and comparing dates are all doable with `Date` objects, so I won't get into that.

If we remove that from the problem, it comes down to finding the segments out of this array:

```
const myArray = [
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 100,
    excluded: false,
  },
  {
    start: 6,
    end: 15,
    excluded: true,
  },
  {
    start: 35,
    end: 50,
    excluded: true,
  },
];
```

The entire solution can be long but this is roughly how you can do it:

- Sort all `start` and `end` values. In the above example, it becomes 1, 6, 15, 35, 50, 100.
- Determine if each segment in the series should be excluded or not.
- Create a new array with that info.
- Merge two adjacent segments with the same `excluded` flag.
- Finally, remove any segments with `excluded: true`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Excluded is used to distinguish breaks from worktime. Merging or excluding makes no sense for this question.

Comment: If you assume there's only one `excluded: false` window, and all `excluded: true` windows are not consecutive, you're right but there's no such condition mentioned in the question, plus it's always better to assume the worst case scenario.

Comment: That doesn't answer my comment in any way. Whatever you are doing has nothing to do what the OP is asking. Excluded means that it's a break, not that the item has to be excluded. Worst case scenario could be your intention, but this is just a random solution that does not apply to this thread..

Comment: On the contrary, this is a nice, on-point answer addressing the problem directly when there's absolutely 0 effort shown in the question without any attempts. We should not feed them to post no-effort questions like this by answering the entire question.

Comment: I'm curious if in your household when you ask someone to fix your toilet, someone comes and gives you a refrigerator. Do you say, "Thank you" or "Sorry but I didn't ask for this"? You give an explanation how to **exclude** and **merge** them based on this flag. **This is not asked at all**. However this is my last attempt. If you want to keep thinking delivering a refrigerator is a good idea, do it.

Comment: That's not a good analogy because what you're describing are two entirely unrelated things. If you care to read my answer, you'll know your analogy is 100% off. If you still think it's unrelated after reading it, I recommend you to spend some time on learning [Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic) or [Deductive reasonsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254494/discussion-between-wimanicesir-and-technophyle).